# Svelte splitter example

Tags: splitter, svelte

I'm looking for a svelte way to adjust the size of a `div` on a page.

there's an example [here](https://codepen.io/lingtalfi/pen/zoNeJp).

I have not found any examples specifically but I'm sure someone has solved this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm thinking using stores is an option.  I'm working on https://svelte.dev/repl/cf13540ebadf406c85f74d007aa2be3b?version=3.6.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `<SplitPane>` component used inside Svelte's own [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl) — example usage: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-repl/blob/d6a99e702d42eb18142dccbd6b766b56b69245e4/src/Repl.svelte#L208-L221

Comment: Thanks Rich, I see it working [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/2b9e2423149741b7af35274094dbc109?version=3.6.7) but I'm not sure why the splitter if not visible or why the text on either side hidden as well.

Comment: I guess what we really need is SplitPane to be a component like svelte-subdivide is

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick implementation of a split pane in svelte, no external library :
https://svelte.dev/repl/b467a4787de3487fbe5c4508e8221268?version=3.42.1

It lets you to chose the minimum width of the panes, and it prevents automatic highlighting of the text in the panes while dragging the splitter.

The component logic is quite simple, so you can change it and adapt it to your project.